# Selenium can't find element by id and xpath

Tags: java, selenium

I read already all the other questions about this topic, there are a lot. I tried some but I do not find error in the code.

I tried adding a timer too to wait for the page to load.

Below the html code and the java:

HTML:

```html
<form id="myform" method="get" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="something1" id="something1.1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="something2" value="" />
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name: </label></td>
            <td><select name="name">
                <option selected="selected" value="1000">FirstNameOnly</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Direction: </label></td>
            <td><select name="Direction">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Choose One</option>
                <option value="UP">UP</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label>Time: </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>From: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="from" id="id6"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>To: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="to" id="id7"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>File type: </label></td>
            <td><span id="id8">
            <input name="fileType" type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" id="id8-0"/><label for="id8-0">Excel</label>
            <input name="fileType" type="radio" value="1" id="id8-1"/><label for="id8-1">CSV</label>
            </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="p::submit" id="id9" value="Preview">
            <input type="submit" name="download" id="ida" value="Download">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JAVA:

```
public void HeadlessChromeStartDownload(){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    if (ValidateOS.isWindows()){
        options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\Juri\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        System.out.println("Windows system");
    } else if (ValidateOS.isUnix()){
        options.setBinary("/path/to/chrome/not/yet/added");
    }

    options.addArguments("--headless --disable-gpu");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("http://localhost/that-test-page.html");
    //WebElement timer = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id8-1")));

    WebElement select1 = driver.findElementByName("FirstNameOnly");
    Select field1 = new Select(select1);
    field1.selectByIndex(1);

    WebElement select2 = driver.findElementByName("Direction");
    Select field2 = new Select(select2);
    field2.selectByIndex(1);

    driver.findElementByName("from").sendKeys("21/06/2017");

    driver.findElementByName("to").sendKeys("22/06/2017");

    /*File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\screen1.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Screen saved");
    } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("Screen NOT saved"); }
    */

    //driver.findElement(By.id("id8-1")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[1]/input[6]")).click();

    //driver.findElementById("ida").click();

    driver.quit();
}
```

**It really does not matter if I use:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id8-1")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElementById("id8-1").click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[1]/input[6]")).click();
```

I can't get Selenium to click on that radio button.
And the same goes for the rest of the code, in fact I used `findElementByName` which obviously is not the best choice.

Thanks to anyone who knows what is wrong with this code!! (: (:

## UPDATE1:

So, I can not explain what happened yesterday. The website I am trying to test was using **id8-1** for that radio button. Today it is **id3-1**, and both the solution with: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='1']")).click();`  or mine: `driver.findElement(By.id("id3-1")).click();` worked.

I'm astonished. It was clearly 8 yesterday.
Still, I do not know if using the cssSelector solution is the best, because I want to work with the IDs.
I upvoted all the answers because all are useful but I wish to use IDs so I'm using my code.. In case of updates by your side I will choose it the one (: (:

Thanks to all!!!

Answer (score 5):

When driving IE with Selenium, I encountered a problem where `driver.find_element_by_id("elem_id")` can't find it but running javascript `document.getElementById("elem_id")` in IE's developer console can. In my case, I was extracting a value. So I worked it around by doing `driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("elem_id").outerText')`

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='fileType' AND @id='id8-1']")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it tomorrow because i left the office already (:

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@name='fileType' AND @id='id8-1'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@name='fileType' AND @id='id8-1']' is not a valid XPath expression.` ):

Answer (score 2):

Does selenium throws an error? When trying to click an element that no longer existis into DOM, you will see an error like 'Element is no longer attached 
to the DOM'.

Better than to using `wait`, is to write a method that verifies if the element is available. Try the following one:

```
private void waitUntilElementExistsAndIsVisible(final By by) {
   new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .pollingEvery(DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
      .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
         public Boolean apply(WebDriver wd) {
            return wd.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
         }
      });
}
```

Use it before executing some action with an element:

```
waitUntilElementExistsAndIsVisible(By.id("id8-1"));
driver.findElement(By.id("id8-1")).click();
```

Another workaround is to use the `Action` methods. Try to move the mouse to the enclosing tag (`<span id="id8">`), and then, click the desired element:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("id8"))).perform();
waitUntilElementExistsAndIsVisible(By.id("id8-1"));
driver.findElement(By.id("id8-1")).click();
```

Comment: The error is: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id8-1"}` although I know there is, because I see it from the page source. But I like this approach you gave me so I will be implementing in the code!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using xpath also

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='1 0r 0']")).click();
```

You can select either 0 or 1 which you want to select

Comment: Thanks! I am not able to try it now, I left the office. I will continue tomorrow!

Comment: Updating the main question!